# find info from xml and convert it to table with python

Tags: python, pandas, xml

So, I want to know one way roads from a city (Mexico, in this case). Using open street maps I select an area, use API surpass and then I obtain this xml downloaded file (I post only a sample, since it's big):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API 0.7.56.9 76e5016d">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2021-05-31T17:31:27Z"/>

  <bounds minlat="19.2768000" minlon="-99.2388000" maxlat="19.5766000" maxlon="-99.0150000"/>

  <node id="30339493" lat="19.4180574" lon="-99.1341026" version="5" timestamp="2021-03-22T18:32:44Z" changeset="101523344" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339495" lat="19.4102743" lon="-99.1353293" version="8" timestamp="2021-03-24T00:39:05Z" changeset="101603421" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339496" lat="19.4078810" lon="-99.1357079" version="3" timestamp="2021-03-24T20:27:00Z" changeset="101672644" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339671" lat="19.3785756" lon="-99.1533804" version="5" timestamp="2021-03-27T00:43:15Z" changeset="101822564" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross"/>
  <node id="30339672" lat="19.3802060" lon="-99.1530728" version="7" timestamp="2021-03-26T23:36:18Z" changeset="101821619" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross">
    <tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="crossing" v="traffic_signals"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
  </node>
  <node id="30339673" lat="19.3818298" lon="-99.1527789" version="4" timestamp="2021-03-27T00:43:15Z" changeset="101822564" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross"/>
  <node id="30339674" lat="19.3845481" lon="-99.1522672" version="6" timestamp="2021-03-27T00:43:15Z" changeset="101822564" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross"/>
  <node id="30339675" lat="19.3864461" lon="-99.1519364" version="4" timestamp="2021-03-27T00:51:05Z" changeset="101822637" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross"/>
  <node id="30339676" lat="19.3885927" lon="-99.1515498" version="7" timestamp="2021-03-27T00:51:05Z" changeset="101822637" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross"/>
  <node id="30339677" lat="19.3900383" lon="-99.1513763" version="8" timestamp="2018-08-17T02:37:05Z" changeset="61731635" uid="2237750" user="chachafish"/>
  <node id="30339687" lat="19.3955112" lon="-99.1510047" version="14" timestamp="2021-04-26T23:03:30Z" changeset="103663923" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339689" lat="19.3983334" lon="-99.1507862" version="6" timestamp="2018-08-17T00:38:58Z" changeset="61730561" uid="2237750" user="chachafish"/>
  <node id="30339690" lat="19.3991201" lon="-99.1507006" version="4" timestamp="2018-08-17T00:38:59Z" changeset="61730561" uid="2237750" user="chachafish"/>
  <node id="30339691" lat="19.4001339" lon="-99.1506290" version="7" timestamp="2021-03-25T23:05:47Z" changeset="101748641" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339693" lat="19.4020539" lon="-99.1504700" version="8" timestamp="2021-03-25T22:14:29Z" changeset="101747430" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339694" lat="19.4038429" lon="-99.1501779" version="7" timestamp="2021-03-25T23:56:53Z" changeset="101749819" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach">
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
  </node>
  <node id="30339698" lat="19.4081297" lon="-99.1494323" version="11" timestamp="2021-03-25T20:28:33Z" changeset="101743733" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339700" lat="19.4099055" lon="-99.1491198" version="8" timestamp="2021-03-25T20:28:33Z" changeset="101743733" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339701" lat="19.4111743" lon="-99.1488803" version="8" timestamp="2021-03-25T20:28:33Z" changeset="101743733" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339769" lat="19.4038133" lon="-99.1486115" version="6" timestamp="2021-03-25T21:55:18Z" changeset="101746967" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339770" lat="19.4037990" lon="-99.1476544" version="6" timestamp="2021-03-25T21:55:18Z" changeset="101746967" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339771" lat="19.4037513" lon="-99.1460243" version="9" timestamp="2021-03-25T21:55:18Z" changeset="101746967" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339772" lat="19.4036933" lon="-99.1450050" version="8" timestamp="2021-03-25T21:55:18Z" changeset="101746967" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach">
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
  </node>
  <node id="30339774" lat="19.4035747" lon="-99.1427250" version="7" timestamp="2020-09-08T23:32:35Z" changeset="90608930" uid="10627270" user="DRM150">
    <tag k="crossing" v="traffic_signals"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
  </node>
  <node id="30339776" lat="19.4034147" lon="-99.1401020" version="11" timestamp="2020-09-08T23:13:10Z" changeset="90608671" uid="10627270" user="DRM150">
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
  </node>
  <node id="30339782" lat="19.4028821" lon="-99.1311222" version="6" timestamp="2020-09-09T14:46:44Z" changeset="90653020" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30339783" lat="19.4029182" lon="-99.1305986" version="7" timestamp="2020-09-09T14:46:44Z" changeset="90653020" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30339784" lat="19.4031193" lon="-99.1295253" version="6" timestamp="2020-09-09T15:12:45Z" changeset="90654079" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30339785" lat="19.4034617" lon="-99.1283113" version="7" timestamp="2021-03-24T19:22:13Z" changeset="101670084" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339786" lat="19.4038564" lon="-99.1269693" version="6" timestamp="2021-03-24T19:22:13Z" changeset="101670084" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30339787" lat="19.4041573" lon="-99.1255939" version="6" timestamp="2020-09-09T15:12:45Z" changeset="90654079" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30339788" lat="19.4042865" lon="-99.1242752" version="4" timestamp="2020-09-09T15:12:45Z" changeset="90654079" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30339789" lat="19.4046213" lon="-99.1225578" version="3" timestamp="2008-06-07T05:58:11Z" changeset="91027" uid="43293" user="ulfinger"/>
  <node id="30339790" lat="19.4051009" lon="-99.1203998" version="11" timestamp="2020-09-09T15:24:44Z" changeset="90654569" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30339791" lat="19.4053145" lon="-99.1190074" version="5" timestamp="2015-04-08T17:59:18Z" changeset="30070321" uid="2191238" user="Abbendymion"/>
  <node id="30339793" lat="19.4053621" lon="-99.1171975" version="9" timestamp="2021-03-19T01:21:52Z" changeset="101291165" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross"/>
  <node id="30339794" lat="19.4053666" lon="-99.1156953" version="8" timestamp="2021-03-19T01:21:52Z" changeset="101291165" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross"/>
  <node id="30339796" lat="19.4055072" lon="-99.1142013" version="7" timestamp="2021-03-19T01:21:52Z" changeset="101291165" uid="11724618" user="TheShiningAlbatross"/>
  <node id="30339797" lat="19.4057371" lon="-99.1132131" version="5" timestamp="2020-09-09T15:40:38Z" changeset="90655167" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30339803" lat="19.4072418" lon="-99.1058510" version="8" timestamp="2020-09-09T20:44:15Z" changeset="90665407" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30339807" lat="19.4085007" lon="-99.0998410" version="9" timestamp="2020-09-09T21:59:56Z" changeset="90667107" uid="10627270" user="DRM150"/>
  <node id="30340060" lat="19.3818489" lon="-99.1799666" version="5" timestamp="2019-02-05T04:15:48Z" changeset="66921681" uid="84642" user="mdelatorre"/>
  <node id="30340062" lat="19.3819030" lon="-99.1789570" version="5" timestamp="2021-04-05T21:55:23Z" changeset="102358661" uid="9917894" user="sasQuach"/>
  <node id="30340068" lat="19.3835914" lon="-99.1753442" version="6" timestamp="2020-10-29T21:00:37Z" changeset="93256736" uid="7674729" user="CoolGuyJake"/>
  <node id="30340069" lat="19.3837083" lon="-99.1752197" version="5" timestamp="2020-10-29T21:00:37Z" changeset="93256736" uid="7674729" user="CoolGuyJake"/>
  <node id="30340070" lat="19.3838234" lon="-99.1750233" version="6" timestamp="2020-10-29T21:00:37Z" changeset="93256736" uid="7674729" user="CoolGuyJake"/>
  <node id="30340073" lat="19.3840632" lon="-99.1721114" version="3" timestamp="2016-03-30T16:04:04Z" changeset="38171525" uid="3677105" user="egvelez"/>
  <node id="30340074" lat="19.3838148" lon="-99.1707408" version="5" timestamp="2017-09-27T05:51:30Z" changeset="52403334" uid="84642" user="mdelatorre"/>
  <node id="30340075" lat="19.3835927" lon="-99.1696958" version="5" timestamp="2020-10-29T16:25:02Z" changeset="93246408" uid="3382594" user="Josuer"/>
  <node id="30340076" lat="19.3832382" lon="-99.1681216" version="5" timestamp="2016-03-30T16:04:07Z" changeset="38171525" uid="3677105" user="egvelez"/>
  <node id="30340084" lat="19.3811483" lon="-99.1586171" version="7" timestamp="2020-10-29T20:02:33Z" changeset="93253814" uid="10456881" user="sbburg">
    <tag k="crossing" v="traffic_signals"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
```

First, I would like to make sense of it (never have used html before). I fathom that some lines are from users who have shared their information about some specific place, to help building the map, but other lines don't make much sense to me.

Second and most important, how can I obtain relevant data for knowing types of roads (the  part, I presume)? I would like to have this in a table to analyze it with pandas. I thought about looping throught lines containing tag (using python, since is nearly the only language I use), and processing it as strings, but im not sure if this would be the best way. I would like to finally obtain something like this:

```
Name               Type     Bicycle  Material  One way  

Perdition road     road     yes      pavement  yes

Penny Lane         Lane     yes      cement    no

Highway to hell    Highway  no       pavement  yes
```

Any help at all would be appreciated, i'm kind of lost in here.

Comment: As we only can see `node` elements in the XML, what constitutes a road? How can you tell if is one-way or not?

Comment: As you can see, where there is the tag line, there is some info on the kind of road it is. I was looking into the file, I was sure it said something about one or two way, but now im not so sure....